# Relative positioning of badge icon relative to badge count

Tags: bug, design, badges

The relative spacing between the badge icon, and the badge-count gives a visual impression that the badges are associated to numbers on the left, which is the wrong number ... let me explain by pictures:

[image: Spacing]

For example, in the above, the badges for janos read like "6 silver, 67 bronze" and in Loki's the bronze `{}` icon is closer to the 43 than the 144, so it looks like 2-silver, and 43 bronze.

This applies for questions/answer taglines too:

See the user profile pages: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

The space to the left of the icon should be increased, and to the right it should be reduced.

[image]

Comment: It would be even clearer if the braces went _around_ the number.

Comment: we gonna investigate this :)

Comment: @200_success there's no chance for that, sory :c